# Create an array from an object with with key and its suffix

Tags: javascript

Looking for help to convert/group an object to an array using a key, the key has a difference with its (-)suffix.

```
const obj = {
    "name-1":"a", 
    "age-1":"20", 
    "email-1":"a@email.com", 
    "name-2":"b", 
    "age-2":"24", 
    "email-2":"b@email.com", 
    "name-3":"c", 
    "age-3":"22", 
    "email-3":"c@email1.com"
};
```

Expected result

```
[
    {
        "name":"a", 
        "age":"20", 
        "email":"a@email.com"
    },
    {
        "name":"b", 
        "age":"24", 
        "email":"b@email.com"
    },
    {
        "name":"c", 
        "age":"22", 
        "email":"c@email.com"
    }
]
```

Maybe due wrong search keyword unable to find a duplicate question.

Comment: I think the reason is that it's not a technical question, but a very simple algorithm question and those are seen like "please do my job".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a `reduce` on `Object.entries` and split the keys say `name-1, age-2` etc by `'-'` and return an array of objects.

```js
const obj = {
    "name-1":"a", 
    "age-1":"20", 
    "email-1":"a@email.com", 
    "name-2":"b", 
    "age-2":"24", 
    "email-2":"b@email.com", 
    "name-3":"c", 
    "age-3":"22", 
    "email-3":"c@email1.com"
};

const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  const [ k, i ] = key.split('-');
  acc[i - 1] = acc[i - 1] || {};
  acc[i-1][k] = value;
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

At the code above inside the `reduce` I split the `key` by `'-'` and it gives me a key of an object and the index of the final array.

Then I check if the index `i - 1` exists in the array. If not then initialized it by an empty object. Here I use `i - 1` because the given object keys are starting from 1 but an array starts from 0.

Finally, I put the object value into the newly created object.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice algorithm question that I will resolve by writing it with ES6 syntax.

You can achieve this thanks to some functions such as [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Example:

```js
const obj = {
    "name-1":"a", 
    "age-1":"20", 
    "email-1":"a@email.com", 
    "name-2":"b", 
    "age-2":"24", 
    "email-2":"b@email.com", 
    "name-3":"c", 
    "age-3":"22", 
    "email-3":"c@email1.com"
};

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  // Here we destructure the entry with on the left the key, and value on the right
  .reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => {
    const [property, index] = key.split('-');
    
    // Get the value currently being filled, or an empty object if it doesn't
    // exist yet.
    const entry = accumulator[index] || {};

    accumulator[index] = {
      // Spread the current entry to which we are adding
      // the property to the object being filled
      ...entry,
      // Dynamic key syntax
      [property]: value,
    };

    return accumulator;
  }, [])
  // Remove "holes" from the array since it's indexed with given keys
  .filter(value => value !== undefined);

console.log(result);
```